# When canvas element is overlap another div ( Safari 5.1/Mac 10.7.1)

Tags: canvas, safari, dhtml

I can't speak English very well.
I develop web-application html5-based.
I've tested safari, chrome, firefox.
It's no problem until safari 5.0.
But after upgrade safari 5.1, it occur this problem only safari 5.1, Mac 10.7.1.

This problem occur when canvas element is overlap another div.

---

```
var d = document.createElement ("div");
document.body.appendChild ( d );

var canvas = document.createElement ("canvas");
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
canvas.style.position = "absolute";
canvas.style.left = "0px";
canvas.style.top = "0px";
canvas.style.width = "100px";
canvas.style.height = "100px";
d.appendChild ( canvas );
var c2d = canvas.getContext("2d");

var d1 = document.createElement ("div");
d.appendChild ( d1 );
d1.style.left = "50px";
d1.style.top = "50px";
d1.style.width = "500px";
d1.style.height = "100px";
d1.style.position = "absolute";
d1.style.overflow = "hidden";
d1.style.backgroundColor = "gray";

var red = document.createElement ("div");
d1.appendChild ( red );
red.style.position = "absolute";
red.style.left = "10px";
red.style.top = "10px";
red.style.width = "100px";
red.style.height = "100px";
red.style.display = "none";
red.style.backgroundColor = "red";

var yellow = document.createElement ("div");
red.appendChild ( yellow );
yellow.style.position = "absolute";
yellow.style.left = "10px";
yellow.style.top = "10px";
yellow.style.width = "50px";
yellow.style.height = "50px";
yellow.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";


var but = document.createElement ("div");
d.appendChild ( but );
but.style.position = "absolute";
but.style.left = "200px";
but.style.top = "10px";
but.style.width = "100px";
but.style.height = "30px";
but.style.backgroundColor = "black";
but.innerHTML = "Click";
but.style.color = "white";

var flag = true ;
but.onmousedown = function ()
{
    var gap = 5 ;
    red.x = 10 ;
    red.style.display = "block";
    var fn = function ()
    {
        red.style.left = (red.x+gap)+"px";
        red.x += gap ; 

        flag = !flag ;
        if ( red.x > 1000 ) return ;
        setTimeout( fn, 10 );
    }

    setTimeout( fn, 10 );

}
```

---

Red-div has Yellow-div as child. If Red-div move, then expect move Yellow-div.
But don't move Yellow-div only safari 5.1 mac 10.7.1.
This problem occur case overlap canvas area and child divs.
And don't occur case not overlap and don't execute " canvas.getContext('2d')".

Is this just Safari Bug?
Any solution?

Thank you.